# how to execute the script in ansible with -y flag

Tags: ansible

I want to execute the script using `ansible-playbook` with `-y` flag. Actually while executing the script it will prompt us to provide the input, so I need to use `-y` flag to skip the providing the input manually. Please suggest below the playbook script module is fine or not?

playbook.yaml

```
 - name: Execute the script
   script:  "/etc/install.sh -y"
```

Comment: What errors are you see with that approach? The `script` module should allow you to provide args that way. Just drop the quotes and do `script: /etc/install -y`

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html, there are two ways to pass arguments in script. Please see below.

```
- name: Run a script with arguments (free form)
  script: /some/local/script.sh --some-argument 1234

- name: Run a script with arguments (using 'cmd' parameter)
  script:
    cmd: /some/local/script.sh --some-argument 1234
```

So you can use the same approach for your playbook as below

```
- name: Execute the script
  script: /etc/install.sh -y
```